# Nginx Proxy for Node.js Returns 400 Under SSL

Tags: nginx

I'm building out a Node.js project and I'd like to stand up an Nginx proxy in front of it. I have the server listening on port 80 just fine, but I'd like it to listen on both (in development). If I try to access the app over SSL, I get a 400 error and the access log entry is just weird (to me):

```
10.0.2.2 - - [06/Feb/2013:15:55:12 +0000] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
```

My `server` block looks like this:

```
server {
  listen      80;
  listen      443 default ssl;
  server_name localhost;

  ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/server.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private/server.key;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/project.access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/project.error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: With recent versions of nginx you don't need `default` in the `listen 443` line. Does `/var/log/nginx/project.error.log` give you any detail about the `400`?

Comment: No errors are reported at all. That's just one of the weird things. I'm nearing that point where I just reboot and hope for the best. Feels like something really flaky is going on...

Comment: What does the request look like that you're sending?

Comment: Are you sure that you're using HTTPS to port 443 (and not HTTP to 443 or HTTPS to 80)? What does the browser report? What does the nginx log contain?

Answer (score 0):

All --

I don't have any idea what was going on, but after bouncing the server, everything is coming up roses. I guess I tripped over my tech karma on my way out the door this morning. The config as shown in my question is now working just fine. For now, I'm willing to chalk it up to the ghost in the machine.

Thanks for trying to help.